# Get raw content of Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, iframe

I want to use Jquery or javascript to get the raw content (mean everycharacter) of an Iframe. It sounds simple but I'm still struggling with finding the right way for it.

For now it is only a XML content in the Iframe though.
Here the code:

```
$(function() {

    var xmlContent = $("#CFrame").contents().find("*").text();

    // The magic
    $('#SResult').xslt({xml: xmlContent, xslUrl: 'stylesheet/designSS.xsl'});
});
```

The html page

```
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" target="ContentFrame" action="http://125.235.8.210:380/search" onSubmit="processContent()">
        .....
    </form>
</div>
<div id="SResult">
</div>
<iframe id="CFrame" name="ContentFrame" frameborder="1" height="2000px" width="1000px" scrolling="no" src="stylesheet/test.xml"></iframe>
</body>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is your iframe pointing to content stored on your domain, or does it point to some remote website? Also, why are you loading an XML document into an iframe?

Comment: There is a form (sent to a remote application) which target this iframe, the return content of the form is the supposely xml. I will then use a style sheet to transform this xml into html contain in a div of the main page.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'll answer your question regardless of whether it is actually an elegant solution to your problem. Joseph seems to take that as the question. I would say he is probably right to do so.

It won't work trying to get the frame using mimetype text/xml. The browser will proceed and 'translate' the XML into HTML. That's why it doesn't sound so simple. This way it is actually impossible.

I present you with a simple work-around for this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getXmlContents() {
    /*
    Note: Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain.
    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp

    */
    var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('greetingFrame').contentDocument;
    if (iframeDocument == null) 
        return undefined;
    var xmlContainer = iframeDocument.getElementById('xmlContainer');
    if (xmlContainer == null)
        return undefined;
    return xmlContainer.innerText == null ? xmlContainer.textContent : xmlContainer.innerText;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="greetingFrame" src="helloworld.html" onload="alert(getXmlContents())">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of the XML are wrapped inside an HTML (helloworld.html):

```
<html>
<body>
<script id="xmlContainer" type="text/xml">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <title>
    Hello world
  </title>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've successfully tested this in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Of course you would have to wrap your XML documents inside a HTML script tag as indicated above. The XML can also be wrapped in a different tag, if you'd like it rendered for example, but you'd have to encode the XML using html encoding. This needs to be done on the server-side. A very simple (php/ruby/python/etc) script would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML resides on your domain, you are better off with AJAX, especially using the [jQuery library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which parses it for you and make it ready for immediate manipulations.

If it does not live on your domain, then [you can't access it via AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless the remote [server and your client's browser both support CORS.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

You have options though:

- If the remote server's API supports JSONP, use it instead of XML. Then you can use jQuery to retrieve JSONP data or roll your own script loader.
- Or use your server to proxy the XML for you. Servers are not restricted to the Same Origin Policy. Create an API on your server that relays your form data to the remote server and retrieve the remote page - all as if your server was the browser. Then forward the results back to you.

Comment: JSONP is not supported, making change on server side is also out of question. Is there a way to set form target to a div or something other than an Iframe. This might help avoiding cross domain rule?

Comment: @MikeNQ JSONP is usually the way around. Other than that, then you are out of luck. The server-proxy would be best for this job.